# Trying to complete simple SQL query involving a case and a table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have an SQL Select query that I am using to return a column of Ids that matched from one table to another and a column of Ids that didn't match. There are a couple other columns that are in the query as well, but they don't matter as much here. There is another column (not currently in the query) in table2 called StatusId. I would like the Ids to only show up in the matched column if the StatusId = 3. Otherwise, I would like them to show up in the Unmatched Column. Sounds super simple, but I can't figure out how to work the `WHERE` statement in.

Query:

```
Select  t2.Id as MatchedId,
case when t2.Id is null
then t1.Id end as UnmatchedId
, t2.Number,t1.Date
from Table1 t1 
left join Table2 t2 
on t2.Id = t1.Id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select  
case when t2.statusid = 3 then t2.Id end as MatchedId,
case when t2.statusid <> 3 then t1.Id end as UnmatchedId
,t2.Number,t1.Date
from Table1 t1 
left join Table2 t2 
on t2.Id = t1.Id;
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yep, thanks! Knew it was really simple, but couldn't get it to work